# Function that receives a string fraction and has to return said fraction reduced

Tags: c#, interview-questions, rational-numbers, factors

I got this exercise on a job interview and i'd like to know how can i improve my code.

Exercise:

Create a function that returns a reduced version of a fraction.

Examples

- Reduce("4/6") = "2/3"
- Reduce("10/11) = "10/11"
- Reduce("100/400") = "1/4";

Notes: a reduced fraction doesn't have a lowest common divisor (except 1) between its numerator and denominator. For example, 4/6 it's not reduced, given that 4 and 6 share 2 as a factor.
If a fraction can be converted to a whole number, it also has to be considered.

My code:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] fractions =
            {
                "-24/12",
                "-3/2",
                "3/-1",
                "-6/-2",
                "3/0",
                "3/8/1",
                "4a/6",
                "2/8a",
                "////"
            };

            foreach (var frac in fractions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{Reduce(frac)}");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static string Reduce(string fraction)
        {
            string[] members = fraction.Split('/');

            // Verify that the fraction received only has two numbers separated by '/' and that its denominator is not 0.
            if (members.Length != 2 || !int.TryParse(members[0], out int numerator) || !int.TryParse(members[1], out int denominator) || denominator == 0)
            {
                return $"Fraction's {fraction} format is incorrect";
            }

            // Check if the received fraction is negative.
            var isNegative = (numerator >= 0 ^ denominator >= 0);

            // Find the greatest common denominator and the reduce.
            numerator = Math.Abs(numerator);
            denominator = Math.Abs(denominator);

            var gcd = GCD(numerator, denominator);

            numerator /= gcd;
            denominator /= gcd;

            // If the fraction is negative, set the numerator to negative.
            if (isNegative) numerator *= -1;

            // Return the reduced fraction
            if (denominator == 1) return numerator.ToString();
            return $"{numerator}/{denominator}";
        }

        // Calculates the greatest common denominator between two positive integers.
        static int GCD(int num, int den)
        {
            int gcd = 1;

            for (int i = 2; i <= num && i <= den; i++)
            {
                if (num % i == 0 && den % i == 0)
                {
                    gcd = i;
                }
            }

            return gcd;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does your code output for `Reduce("4/2")`, `Reduce("4/-6")`,  `Reduce("-6/-2")`, or any ill formated fractions involving 0 or infinity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `GCD`

```
private int CalculateGreatestCommonDenominator(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    int? greatestCommonDenominator = null;

    for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= numerator && divisor <= denominator; divisor++)
        if (numerator % divisor == 0 && denominator % divisor == 0)
            greatestCommonDenominator = divisor;

    return greatestCommonDenominator ?? 1;
}
```

- I would suggest trying to use meaningful / self-expressive names

  - If you are using expressive naming then you can get rid of the *"explanation comments"*
- I always recommend to try to capture the **Why** and **Why not** decisions in the comments. Not the **What** and/or **How**

  - The latter ones should be told by the code itself
  - The formers ones
    are those that are not obvious from the code

    - for example *Why did I choose
      algorithm X instead of algorithm Y?*
- I would also suggest to distinguish **default** and **fallback** values

  - In this case the `1` is the fallback value that's why in my opinion it is better to use that as a fallback

#### `Reduce`

```
public (int dividend, int? divisor) Reduce(string fraction)
{
    string[] members = fraction.Split('/');

    if (members.Length != 2
        || !int.TryParse(members[0], out int numerator)
        || !int.TryParse(members[1], out int denominator)
        || denominator == 0)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"The following fraction '{fraction}' has an incorrect format.");
    }

    var isNegative = numerator >= 0 ^ denominator >= 0;

    var positiveNumerator = Math.Abs(numerator);
    var positiveDenominator = Math.Abs(denominator);

    var gcd = CalculateGreatestCommonDenominator(positiveNumerator, positiveDenominator);

    int semiFinalNumerator = positiveNumerator / gcd;
    int finalNumerator = isNegative ? -1 * semiFinalNumerator : semiFinalNumerator;
    int finalDenominator = positiveDenominator / gcd;

    return finalDenominator == 1
        ?(finalNumerator, null)
        :(finalNumerator, finalDenominator);
}
```

- First of all, do not overwrite your parameters `numerator` and `denominator`

  - Use separate variable for each operator with meaningful names

    - You can avoid to capture the **What** and **How**
  - It also helps debugging
- I would encourage you to return a `ValueTuple` instead of a `string`

  - It helps the caller to process it later (don't need to parse it)
  - It helps the reusability of your code
- If one of the preconditions / prerequisites fails then throw exception (e.g.: `InvalidOperationExcetpion`) than return with a simple string

  - It helps the consumer to decide whether the operation was successful or not
- You can combine the two return statements into a single one

  - Please bear in mind that this requires C# 9 because of [Target-Typed Conditional Expression](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-conditional-expression)

#### `Main`

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("-24/12", -2, null)]
[InlineData("-3/2", -3, 2)]
[InlineData("3/-1", -3, null)]
[InlineData("-6/-2", 3, null)]
public void HappyPath(string fraction, int expectedDividend, int? expectedDivisor)
{
    //Arrange
    var SUT = new Calculator();

    //Act
    var (dividend, divisor) = SUT.Reduce(fraction);

    //Assert
    Assert.Equal(expectedDividend, dividend);
    Assert.Equal(expectedDivisor, divisor);
}
```

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("3/0")]
[InlineData("3/8/1")]
[InlineData("4a/6")]
[InlineData("2/8a")]
[InlineData("////")]
public void UnhappyPath(string fraction)
{
    //Arrange
    var SUT = new Calculator();

    //Act
    Action actualCall = () => SUT.Reduce(fraction);

    //Assert
    var exception = Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(actualCall);
    Assert.Contains(fraction, exception.Message);
}
```

- I would encourage you to write unit tests in order to verify your implementation

  - In this case I've use [parameterised unit test](https://andrewlock.net/creating-parameterised-tests-in-xunit-with-inlinedata-classdata-and-memberdata/)s (PUT) to perform the same assessment for against inputs
- I would also suggest dividing happy and unhappy cases into separate test cases

  - As you can see the unhappy tests can easily decide whether or not the operation has been failed

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Peter, i really appreciate this.

A lot of new concepts for me to dig into, which was pretty much what i was looking for.

Comment: I disagree with the default/fallback distinction, it's arbitrary and not meaningful here. I would fundamentally implement the GCD differently (= using the Euclidean algorithm with recursion) but the use of that nullable mutable variable above makes the code more complex, not less so.

Answer (score 5):

Not bad.

1. Add tests and move examples there.
2. Split long lines:

   ```
   if( members.Length != 2
    || !int.TryParse(members[0], out int numerator) 
    || !int.TryParse(members[1], out int denominator) 
    || denominator == 0
   )
   ```

and lines with several statements:

```
   if (denominator == 1) 
       return numerator.ToString();
```

3. Use [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) for GCD.
4. The function name should probably be Gcd, not GCD (not sure, this depends on guidelines).
5. It will look much more C#ish if there will be a class for fractions, to use it like this:

   ```
   Fraction fraction = Fraction.FromString(frac).Reduce();
   Console.WriteLine($"{fraction}"); //uses ToString method
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your input Pavlo.

When you say 'Add tests and move examples there.', you mean create a small Unit Test project?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about unit test.